# Front-End assets build using gulp in Jenkins CI server

Tags: jenkins, gulp, node-modules

I use Jenkins to deploy a PHP webapp which uses gulp for building its assets (javascripts, styles, image optimization...).

I have a package.json and a gulpfile.js in my repo root folder which are used for development purposes, but I thought it would be a good idea to use them as well to build all my assets from my Jenkins server creating a `gulp build` task.

So this would be the Jenkins deployment process:

1. Download git repo
2. Run tests
3. Create assets from source files in repo
4. Do changes in code for production environment
5. Upload files to production server

in step 3 I have to run `npm install` which takes ages. Is there any way to tell Jenkins to run `npm install` only if package.json has changed from last commit?

Any ideas?

Comment: After one day with no answers I guess it's not an easy problem to solve-improve.  Updating npm made it a little faster, as well as using `npm set progress=false`. Well, I guess 20 extra seconds during deployment is not such a bad thing...